# How to convert a serialized anonymous object back to object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following code:

```
//Convert to string
var Parameters = new { FName = "John", LName = "Doe" };
string str = Parameters.ToString();
                
//Convert back to object and read properties               
dynamic obj = str;
string FirstName = obj.FName;
```

But this doesn't work.  How to do this?  The `str` has a value of `"{ FName = John, LName = Doe }"`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to deserialize... not cast them. You can deserialize using various tools such as newtonsoft

Comment: @Jawad the value in "str" is not json to deserialize using Newtonsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use SerializeObject to change it to json string,and use DeserializeObject to convert it to JObject.

```
var Parameters = new { FName = "John", LName = "Doe" };
string str=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Parameters);             
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(str);
string FirstName = obj["FName"];
```

Answer (score 1):

The ToString() method is not normally used to serialize an object. Instead you probably want to use JsonConvert from the Newtonsoft.Json Nuget package.  To deserialize you would need to create a model (class) for your object. So, I would solve this problem with the following code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Person{
    public string FName {get;set;}
    public string LName {get;set;}
}

public static void Main()
{
    var parameters = new Person{
        FName = "John",
        LName = "Doe"
    };
    //serialize
    var paramsAsString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters);
    
    //deserialize:
    var backToObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(paramsAsString);
    string FirstName = backToObj.FName;     
    Console.WriteLine(FirstName);   //outputs John
}
```

if you need to keep object anonymous you can simply use Object:

```
  var Parameters = new { FName = "John", LName = "Doe" };
        string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Parameters);             
        dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(str);
        string FirstName = obj["FName"];  //outputs John
```

Comment: How to use it without actually creating a class?  I need to do this using anonymous object.

Comment: Most of the functionality of Newtownsoft.Json is now built into the .NET framework library, so you shouldn't need to import Newtownsoft.Json. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0